# Which operations on a collection/its elements are invalidating the enumerator

Tags: c#, collections, enumerator

As stated in the documentation of the [`IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_GetEnumerator)
some operations on the collection may invalidate the enumerator. Its obvious that adding or removing elements will have said effect. But what exactly counts towards modifying the collection? Does the enumerator care about changes to the elements of the collection itself?

The answer to this question may be hidden in the answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261326/collection-modify-item), but I am missing some examples.

Sample code:

```
public class CollectionElement
{
  public CollectionElement(int id, object someProperty)
  {
    ID = id;
    SomeProperty = someProperty;
  }

  public int ID { get; }
  public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class CollectionModifier
{
  // This is the example collection. (List<T> implements ICollection<T>.)
  private List<CollectionElement> collection = new List<CollectionElement>();

  // This is another example. (Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)
  private Dictionary<int, CollectionElement> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, CollectionElement>();

  private void Add(int id, object someProperty)
  {
    CollectionElement newElement = new CollectionElement(id, someProperty);

    // Both statements are obviously invalidating the enumerator of the corresponding collection.
    collection.Add(newElement);
    dictionary.Add(id, newElement);
  }

  private void Remove(int id)
  {
    // Both statements are obviously invalidating the enumerator of the corresponding collection.
    collection.RemoveAll(item => item.ID == id);
    dictionary.Remove(id);
  }

  private void ExchangeListElement(int index, CollectionElement newElement)
  {
    if (index >= collection.Count)
      return;
    // According to the comment by Dennis_E the following statement is invalidating the enumerator of the collection.
    collection[index] = newElement;
  }

  private void ModifyElement(int id, object newValue)
  {
    CollectionElement element = collection.FirstOrDefault(item => item.ID == id);
    if (element == null)
      return;
#warning Is the following statement modifying the collection, hence invalidating the enumerator?
    element.SomeProperty = newValue;
  }

  private void ExchangeElement(int id, CollectionElement newElement)
  {
    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(id, out CollectionElement oldElement))
      return;
#warning Is the following statement modifying the collection, hence invalidating the enumerator?
    dictionary[id] = newElement;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Does the enumerator care about changes to the elements of the collection itself?` -- No.  Collections store *references* to objects, not the actual objects themselves.  The only exception might be ordered collections that store objects which implement the `IComparable` interface.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So I guess `ModifyElement` would not invalidate the enumerator. But what about `ExchangeElement`?

Comment: @FLav0ured If you want to know if that specific snippet will throw an exception or not the fastest way to find out is to run it and see what happens.

Comment: In the case of `List<T>`, the enumerator checks if the `_version` variable has changed. You can look through the source of `List<T>` to find all occurrences. 
Basically, `_version` is incremented when the contents of the list changes. Adding an item, removing an item, setting an item through the indexer and sorting the list all change the contents of the list. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: @Dennis_E: I didn't know that about `List<T>`, espeically "setting an item through the indexer."

Comment: @Dennis_E Thank you for your comment. I added another example within the sample code and I will follow your advice on looking through the source of Dictionary<TKey, TValue> to find out if the same holds true for the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely up to the implementation.  It's not even true that adding or removing elements needs to invalidate the enumerator.  It's up to the implementation of the iterator (and potentially the details of the underlying collection) to determine what types of changes to the underlying collection make it no longer possible to continue enumerating it, and which changes can still allow the iterator to continue.

Some implementations go for the simplest option and say that *any* change to the collection invalidates the enumerator (many of the .NET collections are implemented this way), others are able to continue iterating the sequence regardless of any changes to the underlying collection at all.  Some are in between.

If you want to know how a given sequence you have will behave if you change a collection it's based off of, you'll have to see the documentation for that collection, or whatever generated the sequence for it.  If you're creating your own collection and/or iterator for a collection, then it's up to you to decide what types of changes make it no longer sensible to have any existing iterators continue processing, or whether it's worth your time (and the associated performance costs) to support some/all changes to the underlying collection while still having a sensible behavior for sequences being iterated on.

Comment: Increasingly, I'm finding that having access to the Framework Source is more than a little useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The vast majority of iterators of framework collections are specifically documented as saying that *any* changes to the underlying collection invalidate them, and the exceptions are specifically documented as explaining that they don't.  While there are some things that are easier to look up, I'd say that this specific behavior is easier to see from the documentation than the source code.

Comment: In general, only changes to the collection that *change the size of the collection* are likely to disrupt the enumerator in any meaningful way.  Of course, if you swap out a particular object midstream and expect the original object to still be there in the same slot, well.

Comment: @Servy To be honest your answer made me very confused at first. Theres so much more about collections that I have to learn. Yet I am glad that I asked and that you answered. At least now I know that my previous assumptions were leading me into the wrong direction. Thanx.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Servy answer:

```
private int? _someValue;
public IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
{
   if(_someValue != null)
   {
       yield return _someValue.Value;
   }
}
```

The only one responsible for correctness of this code - is code owner. If you allow enumeration when _someValue changed to null - you will get a NullReferenceException in multithreaded environment. It's even worse if your object holds state:

```
private bool _isBlack = false;
private bool _isWhite = true;
public IEnumerable<string> GetValues()
{
   if(_isBlack)
   {
       yield return "black";
   }
   if(_isWhite)
   {
       yield return "white";
   }
}
```

In this example if someone started enumeration, skipped to word "white" then someone enabled black - the one enumerating will not get this "black" value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with invalidating an iterator while iteration is in progress, because that iterator can't possibly be invalidated while it's in progress, it can only ever complete after yielding the first item.  This is only ever talking about the semantics of what this one iterator should yield, when the underlying data source never changes.

Comment: I have added example with explicit state.